# In Python how can I extract and consolidate 3 rows, and also provide a value count?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am wanting to extract the following:

| ID | Name | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Red | 5 |
| 123 | Red | 4 |
| 123 | Red | 3 |
| 123 | Red | 5 |
| 123 | Red | 4 |
| 123 | Red | 3 |
| 456 | Blue | 8 |
| 456 | Blue | 4 |
| 456 | Blue | 3 |
| 789 | Yellow | 6 |
| 789 | Yellow | 8 |

And basically return this:

| ID | Name | Rating | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Red | 4 | 6 |
| 456 | Blue | 5 | 3 |
| 789 | Yellow | 7 | 2 |

(ID and Name have been consolidated, rating is returning and average, and there is also a value count of the previously unique rows)

I have tried all manner of things with pandas.groupy but it doesn't seem to like this number of columns... Best I have managed is the following:

```
newtable = data.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)['Rating'].mean()
```

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `data.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).agg(Rating=('Rating','mean'), Count=('Name','size'))`

Comment: Thanks so much! This works really well. Quick question: How can I also keep the ID column in my results?

Comment: Here are same values per groups `Name`, so use `data.groupby(['ID','Name'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(Rating=('Rating','mean'), Count=('Name','size'))`